# Foreign Key based on the sum of a related table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm wondering if this is at all possible.

I was looking through normal forms on wikipedia and came across the [Domain/key normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/key_normal_form). I have a similar set up to the second set of tables in the referenced link. However, what if I wanted to not have a "Net Worth in Dollars" column, but instead had another table that listed all of their sales. Is there a way to set the Wealthiness Status via foreign key based on the sum of their sales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I figured out a better way to do this. And that is by using an `after insert` trigger. [Here is a fiddle for it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e755/1/0)